# Terraform for iterate through nested lists

Tags: terraform, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have resource input defined in yaml file , in  main.tf i am using yamldecode to retrieve resource properties . In general its working when i have string value for role "roles: ADMIN". But i need my resource iterate based on list value defined in roles. Please advise.

I have tried terraform "count" argument and i am getting error as below

Error: Invalid combination of "count" and "for_each"
│
│   on main.tf line 214, in resource "snowflake_schema_grant" "grant":
│  214:           for_each = { for ac in local.acs : ac.databasename => ac }
│
│ The "count" and "for_each" meta-arguments are mutually-exclusive, only one should be used to be explicit about the number of resources to be created.

```
 grants:
  - schemaname: SCHEMA1
    databasename: DEMO
    privilege:  MODIFY
    roles: [ADMIN,SYSADMIN]
  
  - schemaname: SCHEMA2
    databasename: DEMO
    privilege:  USAGE
    roles: [USER1,USER2]


locals {
        acs = yamldecode(file("./access.yaml"))
      }
resource "snowflake_schema_grant" "grant" {
          for_each = { for ac in local.acs.grants : ac.schemaname => ac }
          #count = length(each.value.privilege)           
          database_name     = each.value.databasename
          schema_name  = each.value.schemaname
          privilege = each.value.privilege
          roles    = each.value.roles 
 }
```

I would like to run my resource iterate 4 times as follows

- DEMO, SCHEMA1,MODIFY, AMDIN
- DEMO, SCHEMA1, MODIFY, SYSADMIN
- DEMO,SCHEMA2, USAGE, USER1
- DEMO, SCHEMA2, USAGE, USER2

Comment: "Count or Join is not working" - what does it mean? Any errors? What is `schemagrants`?

Comment: @Marcin sorry, i have simplified it now. hope now question is clear ?

Comment: Are you sure this is your correct yaml? Because the second half fully overwrites the first one.

Comment: @Marcin you are correct, i copied wrong yaml. Please see the image of working yaml with one role. but i want to repeat resource in case list is provided to roles

Comment: I've noticed that all almost your questions got answered yet only two answers were ever accepted. Accepting useful answers is not only a good practice, but reduces duplicates and increases chances of your questions being actually answered.

Comment: Its working @Marcin , thanks a lot. I have cleaned up partial answer from question , so now we have yours as final answer. hope you agree ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expected output is confusing. For example, it contains `TESTSCH` which is not part of your yaml. Your yaml has `SCHEMA2` which is not used at all. So I can just guess what you want to do.

Anyway, you have to **flatten** your double-loop, into a single `for_each`. This can be done as follows:

```
locals {
    acs = yamldecode(file("./access.yaml"))
        
    acs_flat = merge([
            for idx, ac in local.acs["grants"]:
             {
                 for role in ac["roles"]:
                   "${idx}-${role}" => {
                       schemaname = ac["schemaname"]
                       role = role
                       privilege =  ac["privilege"]
                       databasename =  ac["databasename"]
                   }
             }
            
        ]...)    
        
}

resource "snowflake_schema_grant" "grant" {
      for_each      = local.acs_flat       
      database_name = each.value.databasename
      schema_name   = each.value.schemaname
      privilege     = each.value.privilege
      roles         = [each.value.role]
 }
```